# .replace() of newline doesn't work with a contenteditable item

Tags: javascript, replace

I have this simple code:

```
 <div style="margin-left:10px;">
    <p>
     <a class="btn" href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div style="margin-left:10px;">

    <div id="example-one" >
      <p id="textEditor" contenteditable="true"></p>
    </div> 

  </div>



 <script type="text/javascript">



function myFunction()
{

  // removes <div> from #textEdtor's content
  $("#textEditor>div").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); }); 

  var str=document.getElementById("textEditor").innerHTML; 

  var n=str.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<br>')

  document.getElementById("textEditor").innerHTML=n;

  alert(n);
}

</script>
```

The problem is that the `var n=str.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<br>')` doesn't work when user press enter. Although it works very well if i use this `.replace(/\[b\]/g,'<b>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g,'</b>')`

It only adds a `<br>` only if you press twice the enter.

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: If you log str to the console, are the newlines there? `console.log(str)` and see if it's multiline.  If so, take it into a text editor or an online JS regex editor and start playing with it there.  Hard to tell without a working example to look at, though.  Consider putting a working example up on jsfiddle.net

Comment: `contenteditable` inserts `<br>` for you .. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it inserts `<div>` blocks, but not `<br>` tags.

Comment: @Eli Gassert it returns the same thing in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in removing child `<div>` elements. Replace your code with the one below, and everything should work fine:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#textEditor > div").before("<br />").contents().unwrap();
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Hm7DY/